# How to decorate a GTK window like eg. the gnome-panel?

Tags: application-development, gtk, programming

I would like to make a panel-like application, in appearance much like the gnome-panel. I would like to use GTK for this (although i've also looked into Qt), preferably using Python.

How can i decorate the window in such a way a color/gradient/bitmap/svg is applied to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was provided on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868114/how-to-decorate-a-gtk-window-like-eg-the-gnome-panel).